# How to add a component inside accordion

Tags: sxa, presentation

I have to add a checklist filter component inside SXA accordion component .Can it be achieved in SXA?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add any component inside the SXA Accordion component, each accordion item by default has a Page Content component added in the "section-content" placeholder, you can either delete or keep this component, and you can add your CheckList Filter in the "section-content" placeholder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The accordion is a composite rendering means you can use any other rendering/component with this. So to answer your question, yes we can use checklist filter component inside SXA accordion component. Once you'll drop accordion component, you can expand the slide to put additional rendering inside it.

[image]

Refer this doc: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-accordion-and-tabs.html

Comment: But after adding the accordion and expanding it instead of place holder content is coming i,.e to add rich text for me.Am I missing some thing

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? Or add a screenshot? I think you might have a placeholder settings issue but not sure as your problem is unclear for me.

Comment: For you a place holder is showing up automatically whenever you are adding the accordion for me it showing a page content,is there any place holder setting ?